# Rerun option Pipeline Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am implementing Jenkins pipeline in Jenkins version 2.8. everything works great so far, but I would like to implement rerun option as a tick box.

My Pipline has 4 stages:

1. Stage
2. Stage
3. Stage
4. Stage

I run the pipeline and it fails at 2. Stage.
Now I have build #1 that failed at 2. Stage, what I would like to do now is to build #2 and have a parameter option to rerun, meaning that if I select rerun option next build would pick up from the point that the previous build failed and continue from there.

Build #1 -> Failed at 2. Stage

Build #2 -> Skip 1. Stage, Continue from 2. Stage as it failed in prevoius build.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CloudBees has support for this in their enterprise version of Jenkins, use the pipeline step [checkpoint](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html?q=checkpoints#workflow).

Unfortunately, being enterprise you will have to pay a significant amount of money to get access to this plugin. Instead, what you can do is a lot of manual coding. In short I would solve it in the following way:

1. Determine if the build is a rebuild of previous build. This can be solved by parameterizing the build.
2. When build finishes stage 1, archive all resource which is needed later steps, in the case that it is a rerun, then I would skip the regular part of stage 1 and instead retrieve the artifacts from previous build using Copy Artifact Plugin. It might be useful to archive the retrieved artifacts directly so that the rebuild can be rebuilt again.
3. Stage 2 shouldn't need to do something extra, as long as all the resources that it need is restored by stage 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like serialization of the number of the failed stage

```groovy
String fileName= 'stageNumber.txt'
sh ("wget ${env.JENKINS_URL}/job/$yourJobName/lastBuild/artifact/$fileName")//will be failed on the first build
failedStage= readFile(fileName)
try {
    stage('First stage') {}//add if condition}
    stage('Second stage') {
        if (failedStage == '2') {
            println('Skip 2. Stage, Continue from 3. Stage as it failed in prevoius build.')
        } else {
           doSomething()
           failedStage = '2'
    }
    stage('Last stage') {}//here failedStage could be zero for use in other if
} finally {
    writeFile(file: fileName,
              text: failedStage)
    archiveArtifacts(fileName)
}
```